# Vuetify change page showing in Vuetify-2 data-table

Tags: vuetify.js

I would like to change the page showing in Vuetify (version 2) data-table to one (first page) when new data arrives from server. My understanding is that :pagesync could be used but I have not been able to figure out how to do this.
 Can someone help?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Solved by watching incoming data, binding :options to v-data-table and changing the options object from watcher to include the desired page (in my case page:1) when data changed.